# How to call xdmp:eval() with transaction-id option?

Tags: marklogic

I'm creating a set of MarkLogic REST extensions that will be used in Mulit-Statement ACID Transactions.

The underlying code will call `xdmp:eval()` with a `transaction-id` option.

Unfortunately, the `transaction-id` option is not documented.

Can someone please provide an example of using `xdmp:eval()` with a `transaction-id` option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The option (usable on eval or invoke) is called (creatively) `transaction-id`.

You can see an example in the `eput:invoke-transaction()` function within *Modules/MarkLogic/rest-api/lib/endpoint-util.xqy*

Expected Caveat:  Because it is undocumented, use at your own risk. The Support organization probably won't be in a position to answer questions about it.